# How to backup SQL Server 2019 Express and upload to Azure Blob with 120 days retention

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

How to backup SQL Server 2019 Express and upload it to Azure Blob with days retention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download [AzCopy 8.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#previous-version) and [SqlPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. Add a Command with a Script below

   ```
   cls
   forfiles /p "%CD%" /s /m *.* /D -120 /C "cmd /c del @FILE"
   echo -- BACKUP DATABASE --
   set DATABASENAME={Your db name}

   :: filename format Name-Date (eg MyDatabase-2009.5.19.bak)
   set DATESTAMP=%DATE:~-4%.%DATE:~7,2%.%DATE:~4,2%
   set BACKUPFILENAME=%CD%\\%DATABASENAME%-%DATESTAMP%.bacpac
   echo.

   SqlPackage.exe /a:export /scs:"Server=(local);Database=%DATABASENAME%;Trusted_Connection=True;" /tf:"%BACKUPFILENAME%"


   AzCopy /Source:%BACKUPFILENAME% /Dest:https://myseogenie.blob.core.windows.net/db-bacup/%BACKUPFILENAME% /DestKey:{YOUR_KEY_HERE}/Y


   echo -- BACKUP DONE--
   ```
3. You can create a Windows Scheduler to run it daily

Comment: If you copied this code from somewhere, please attribute

Comment: OK apologies for the accusation. You should be able to accept your answer.